# MySQL performance and design for very large tables

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am designing a new MySQL database (using InnoDB as the engine) that will host tables into which large amounts of data are being logged (around 2 million records per day, 5 years worth of data kept = approx 3 650 000 000 rows).  Now, clearly it is not a very smart idea to store all of this in a single table, so these are pretty much my options:

1. Use partitioning on the table *(how much of an improvement will this really offer at this scale?)*
2. Generate a new table to contain a single month's data each *(so, around 60 000 000 rows per table)*

It needs to also be noted that I will have to do some kind of multi-master replication (or clustering).

Now, I'm thinking **option 2** may be the better one, as it will allow for the smallest possible set of data to be queried (when the user specifies the dates to search), and will also simplify archiving of data after 5 years (just move the entire table).  However, using option 2 means that I will have to either make use of joins, unions, or I'll have to run multiple separate queries in order to generate a resultset (the latter is not preferred if you need to order by something other than date).

So, my question is, **is there a way to run the query in parallel across the multiple tables in a way that will really put the focus on speed, other than by using joins?**.  I'm thinking of guys like Google who are able to achieve their speed in searches by doing more or less this type of thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Buddy i would suggest you to go for some Big data based database like Mongodb. there you can get both features like efficiently handling big data as well as fast query processing.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard some good things about MongoDB, and also PostgreSQL.  I've been using MySQL for the past 10 years though, and it isn't a bad system, so was hoping to stick to the familiar.  Will something like MongoDB be able to handle such a large table, or would I still need to split up the tables?

Comment: yeah MongoDB can handle this. In Mysql rather than going with your second option i would suggest to implement it with some row based mechanism like if there will more than x rows you will create a new table. and also put indexes for the column which will be used for query

Comment: I found this link, which suggests that I should be able to come right with MySQL quite easily, even with what I consider to be a large load (if one of the FB MySQL engineers saw this post they'd probably laugh and mumble "amateur...").  [Facebook shares some secrets on making MySQL scale](http://gigaom.com/2011/12/06/facebook-shares-some-secrets-on-making-mysql-scale/).